# Dragging multiple QGraphicsItems in different QGraphicsScenes for the same amount

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I have my own classes (MyGraphicsScene, MyGraphicsView, MyGraphicsItem) derived from QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView and QGraphicsItem.

In my main window, I then create nine (9) instances of MyGraphicsScene, shown through nine instances of MyGraphicsView.  All nine MyGraphicsScenes contain pointers to each other.

How can I drag an instance of MyGraphicsItem in one MyGraphicsScene, and then automatically drag certain MyGraphicsItem instances (in the eight remaining MyGraphicsScenes) for the same amount/distance/vector?

My first idea was to reimplement MyGraphicsItem::itemChange (with change == QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionChange) and then call setPos() for remaining instances of MyGraphicsItem (contained within other MyGraphicsScenes). However this won't work because I will get infinite recursion (setPos() would trigger itemChange() as well, including for the originating MyGraphicsItem).

Any other ideas from experienced Qt-ers?

Answer (score 1):

I do know for a fact you can use the same `QGraphicsScene` in multiple views. So if you're just trying to have multiple views of the same thing, call `MyGraphicsView` all with the same scene.

Answer (score 0):

If you define  derived class for QGraphicsItem (I think you already have, right?) and reimplement the `mouseMoveEvent` so it calls the move method to all 9 objects.

Remember that you have at your disposal all the attributes of `QMouseEvent`, e.g. `buttons()`, `pos()`.

```
void MyGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent( QMouseEvent *event )
{
  if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) {
    QPoint pos = event->pos();
    // ...
  }
}
```

Hope that helped!